# how to know iphone applicaton template?

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates, xcode-template

already iphone implemented app running on xcode so how you know, which type of iphone template (view based or window or tab based....)is selected while development?

Comment: why do you need this information? An average iOS developer can turn every template into every other template within 10 minutes. Those templates don't limit your project in any way.

Comment: i know, its just come in my mind that if new iPhone developer want then how he or she can get ...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. The template is just something to get you started. You can still change your app to be however you like after you've started development.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because all that templetes are just conventionalities. However if there is tab bar controller, then you can suppose that this is tab based app.